# Why we add keys to the the key store?

Tags: aura

I am following this tutorial to add trusted nodes to a network:

https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-blockchain/add-trusted-nodes/

My question is, in the tutorial, we need to add aura and grandpa keys to the keystore on local machine. Why this step is needed? What is the purpose of adding keys to the key store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keys are incorporated into a keystore due to their requirement by consensus algorithms for signing consensus messages. The keystore serves as a secure repository for these keys, offering an organized and safeguarded means of storing them. Essentially, the keystore is an ideal container for holding the keys, ensuring their protection while fulfilling the needs of consensus algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

Your node needs the private keys to sign e.g. blocks or grandpa commits